# How to select rows from index column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing

I want to use a `for-loop` to find the consecutive time periods based on another column `data` in `df`, ie. time periods(defined using start & end timestamps) where `data`>20.
In `df`, `timestamp` is made the index. I think the issue is that in the loop, I didn't specify correctly to select the row from the index column in a dataframe.

`for-loop`:

```
for i in range(len(df3)): 
    if i >0:

        activities = []          
        start_time = None          

        if (df.loc[i, 'data'] >= 20):                                   

            if start_time == None:   
                start_time = df.loc[i, 'timestamp']
        else:

            if start_time != None:
                end_time = df.loc[i-1, 'timestamp']

                duration = (end_time - start_time).seconds
                activities.append((duration, start_time, end_time))
                start_time = None 

return activities
```

`df`:

```
                        id      timestamp               data    Date        sig     events
timestamp                           
2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 40250   2020-01-15 06:12:49.213 20.0    2020-01-15  -1.0    1.0
2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 40251   2020-01-15 06:12:49.313 19.5    2020-01-15  1.0     0.0
2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 40256   2020-01-15 08:05:10.083 20.0    2020-01-15  1.0     0.0
```

It returned:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-9853026603d5> in <module>()
      9 
     10 
---> 11         if (df.loc[i, 'data'] >= 20):                                   
     12 
     13             if start_time == None:

7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _invalid_indexer(self, form, key)
   3074         """
   3075         raise TypeError(
-> 3076             f"cannot do {form} indexing on {type(self)} with these "
   3077             f"indexers [{key}] of {type(key)}"
   3078         )

TypeError: cannot do index indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'> with these indexers [1] of <class 'int'>
```

---

Update:

As suggested by @jcaliz, I tried the code below, and changed the indentations for `return` for different variations:

```
for i in range(len(df)): 
    if i >0:

        activities = []           
        start_time = None          


        if (df.iloc[I].data >= 20):                                   
            if start_time == None:   
                start_time = df.iloc[i].timestamp
        else:

            if start_time != None:
                end_time = df.iloc[i-1].timestamp

                duration = (end_time - start_time).seconds
                activities.append((duration, start_time, end_time))
                start_time = None


return activities
```

but had the same error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-24-d78e4605aebe>", line 31
    return activities
                            ^
SyntaxError: 'return' outside function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loc` is used for text, not an integer based index, use `iloc` instead. Change:

```
if (df.loc[i, 'data'] >= 20):
```

To

```
if (df.iloc[i].data >= 20):
```

The same would apply for the other `loc`s like `df.loc[i, 'timestamp']`

**Edit:**

A better way would be not using for loop

1. `start_time` is the same as `timestamp`
2. `end_time` is the previous's `timestamp`
3. `duration` is the difference in seconds

The process would be:

```
# Assign previous record's timestamp as end time
df['end_time'] = df['timestamp'].shift(1)

df['duration'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['end_time'] -
                                     x['timestamp']).seconds, axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi @jcaliz, thank you for the answer. It returned `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Do you know what that means?

Comment: Yes, it means the `iloc` returned a series, but you wanted, the single value as float/integer to compare against `20`, check the edit I made.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have removed the previous error! But it returned ` File "<ipython-input-24-d78e4605aebe>", line 31
    return activities
                            ^ SyntaxError: 'return' outside function` despite the fact that I changed the indentation many times. Do you know how I can get the `activities` table, with `start_time` and `end_time` for each activity?

Comment: Hi jcali, that's a good idea. I tried something on my own with your edited code but didn't get it working unfortunately, probably because of me not familiar with coding yet. Could you please add the entire code? Thanks a million..

Comment: That is actually the whole code, post the error you are seeing and I can help you.

Comment: Hi jcaliz, the code is a bit lengthy so I've posted it in the chat room. Is it still open?